# How can the class constructor inherited from the base class assign only positive values?

Tags: c#

How can the class constructor inherited from the base class assign only positive values?

Base class :

```
abstract class Wallet
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public Wallet(decimal amount)
    {
        Amount = amount;
    }
}
```

Derived class:

```
class Account : Wallet
{
    public Account(decimal amount) : base(amount)
    {
        if (amount >= 0)
        {
            Amount = amount;
        }
    }
}
```

I set a negative number as a parameter, and it passes the condition

```
Account account = new Account(-50);

Console.WriteLine(account.Amount);//return -50
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We have no idea what the base class is here, or what it does.

Comment: To be clear - are you saying that the base should only assign in the event the amount is >= 0 or that the operation should fail with an InvalidOperationException or similar when you attempt to do it. As @JonSkeet says, hard to understand the intention without understanding whether the base class allows creation without setting the amount for instance?

Comment: Can you share the relevant code of base class too?

Comment: I edited and added to make it clearer

Comment: The base class constructor is already setting `Amount` to the value passed in via the parameter - so the `Account` constructor body is entirely redundant. It's saying "if the `amount` parameter is greater than or equal to 0, set the `Amount` property to the value it already has" effectively. What do you *want* to happen if `amount` is less than 0?

Comment: @JonSkeet I would like the negative values ​​not to be assigned

Comment: So if the negative values are not assigned, what should account.Amount return? An exception, null or 0? I'm assuming you just want it to be 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `ctor` of the derived class to this

```
public Account(decimal amount) : base(amount >= 0 ? amount : 0)
```

Here a demonstration of the code:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/kHvHiH

Or if you want to throw an exception you can do this instead

```
public Account(decimal amount) : base(amount >= 0 ? amount : throw new NotSupportedException())
```

See a demonstration here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/eXB98r

(This code requires c# 7 as a minimum)